# is it possible to have a union and a outer join together?

Tags: sql, oracle, union, outer-join

So my issue here is the 'ON' clause will not meet the delete condition if people get delete out of the source tables. Is there a way to do a outer join on the union to include if anything gets deleted for the delete part to work? This something that would run ever 5 minutes. Sorry if this is a bad example of what im trying to do.

```
merge into table_one ab
using ( select people,job from table_jobs
where job = 'police'
union
select b.people,b.job from second_table_jobs b
where b.job = 'firefighter') zba
on (ab.people = zba.people)
update 
set 
ab.job ='firefighter'
where b.people = ab.people
and zba.job <> ab.job
delete where zba.people <> ab.people
when not matched then
insert 
(
people,
job
)
values
(
zba.people,
zba.job
)
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing the `when matched then` before the `update`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a separate `DELETE` statement using `NOT EXISTS` to keep it clean.

```
DELETE FROM table_one ab
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   (SELECT people,
                                  job
                           FROM   table_jobs
                           WHERE  job = 'police'
                           UNION
                           SELECT b.people,
                                  b.job
                           FROM   second_table_jobs b
                           WHERE  b.job = 'firefighter') zba
                   WHERE  ab.people = zba.people);
```